# How can maximum runtime in Colab be extended?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I use ColabPro for my deep learning work. Currently the ETA for every epoch is ~26 hours. I use the following code to avoid disconnection in the console:

```js
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Clicked on connect button"); 
    document.querySelector("colab-connect-button").click()
}setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

This code does maintain the interaction with Colab window.
However, I would like to know if this will help to automatically reconnect and get the code running beyond 24 hrs i.e. maximum runtime of ColabPro?

Comment: Colab does not want you to run over 24hrs. I would be more concerned about your model, 26 hrs for an epoch is a seriously large model and dataset. Unless you really know what you're doing that sounds like a problem. If you are making such complicated models you should be using a professional framework like AWS Sagemaker and implement distributed learning on multiple devices.

If you must use colab try out distributed TPU training to reduce runtime. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu

Comment: So, you mean javscript will not work when the runtime crosses 24 hrs to maintain the thread and all parameters will be reset? Thanks a lot. I will try out distributed TPU training. I guess another option can be saving the model every n batches within an epoch? Also, the reason behind high ETA is the data generator in my case as the model is simple enough.

Comment: It may work, I'm just thinking that relying on a process that subverts googles goals with Colab is a good way to have bugs or get banned. You should save your model often but I would save it to your google drive not the local instance in case something go awry. Have you tested this model at all? Is it a premade model? Training something large and untested professionals have not made is a recipe for wasted training time.

Comment: Yes, I meant saving the model every n-batches to google drive. The model architecture is pre-existing.

Comment: Is your data located on a cloud? If you are loading the data from the cloud to Colab that could explain why it is taking so long.